# Heroku. Cookies work but not sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, cookies, session-cookies

Can someone explain why cookies works on Heroku but not sessions.

Following methods will output a number that will be increased every time the page get refreshed. Both examples works on my local environment but differs on Heroku.

**Sessions** does **NOT** work on **Heroku**

```
def test
  if !session[:x]
    session[:x] = 0
  end
  session[:x] = session[:x].to_i + 1
  render plain: session[:x].to_s
end
```

**Cookies** **does** work on **Heroku**

```
def test
  if !cookies[:x]
    cookies[:x] = 0
  end
  cookies[:x] = cookies[:x].to_i + 1
  render plain: cookies[:x].to_s
end
```

**Why not session?**

I need sessions to work and I'm happy for any idea. I'm new to rails and Heroku so I might have been missing something very basic. Do I need to do a setting in rails or Heroku?

My settings...

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
end
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
end
```

config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session', domain: :all
```

Comment: Please show how you configured your session storage in development and on production.

Comment: Is that all files setting files that would be related? @spickermann

Comment: How many dynos do you have running?

Comment: How do I know how many dynos I'm running? According to the my apps dyno config I'm using "Free dynos". But I don't know how many that is.